# The `resetpassword` utility is failing to find users on the selected drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, password, recovery, administrator

I booted into Recovery Mode and launched the Terminal to run the `resetpassword` utility. After selecting the drive to reset passwords for, I'm seeing:

```
There are no users on this volume to reset the password for.
```

I've ran `Disk Utility` to fix the drive. I've also reinstalled the OS, but I still can't reset the password.

Why does the `resetpassword` utility think there are no users? I looked at the `passwd` file and they all seem to be there.

I'm running `macOS Sierra`.

Comment: I'm very confused about your computer's state and how it got there. macOS doesn't use `passwd` except early in the startup process and single-user mode, and user accounts are not normally listed there. Instead, normal accounts are in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/*.plist`. How did your accounts get in `passwd` and if they're there, why didn't an OS reinstall replace the file (and therefore remove them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by re-running the Apple Setup Assistant by booting into single-user mode,  `mount -uw /`, removing the `.AppleSetupDone` file from `/var/db` directory and rebooting which re-runs the Apple Setup Assistant to create users.